# How to double a list using tail recursive?

Tags: racket, tail-recursion

```
(define (lst-double-helper lst acc)
  (if (empty? list)
      acc
      (lst-double-helper (rest lst) (cons (* (first lst) 2) acc))))

(define (lst-double lst)
  (lst-double-helper lst '()))
```

I feel I'm doing it in the right way. But this gives me an error

```
(lst-double '(1,2,3))
*: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: ',2
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
```

Why do it expect the second argument to be a number?

Comment: Get rid of the commas, and write either `'(1 2 3)` or `(list 1 2 3)`. Commas mean something entirely different.

Comment: because you're multiplying each element of the list by 2. so it must be a number to participate in the multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of comments:

- List elements are separated by spaces, not commas. That's the error being reported.
- The base case of the recursion must refer to the parameter `lst`, not to `list`.
- Your tail-recursive solution reverses the list, an extra `reverse` is needed at the end to restore the original order

With the above changes in place, it works as expected:

```lisp
(define (lst-double-helper lst acc)
  (if (empty? lst) ; parameter is called `lst`
      acc
      (lst-double-helper (rest lst) (cons (* (first lst) 2) acc))))

(define (lst-double lst)
  (reverse ; required to restore original order
   (lst-double-helper lst '())))

(lst-double '(1 2 3)) ; use spaces to separate elements
=> '(2 4 6)
```

Be aware that a tail-recursive solution that traverses an input list and `cons`es its elements to build an output list, will necessarily reverse the order of the elements in the input list. This is ok, and it's normal to do a `reverse` at the end. Possible alternatives to avoid reversing the elements at the end would be to reverse the input list at the beginning or to write a non-tail-recusive solution.

Answer (score 1):

One such way is by using continuation-passing style. Here we add a parameter named `return` which effectively encodes a return-like behavior with a lambda. `double` now takes *two* arguments: the list to double, `xs`, and the continuation of the result, `return` –

```
(define (double xs return)
  (if (empty? xs)
      (return empty)
      (double (cdr xs)
              (lambda (result)
                (return (cons (* 2 (car xs))
                              result))))))
```

As an example, the result of `double` applied to a list of `'(1 2 3)` is sent to `print`

```
(double '(1 2 3) print)
;; '(2 4 6)
;; => #<void>
```

`double` evaluates to whatever the final continuation evaluates to; in this case, `print` evaluates to `#<void>`. We can use the `identity` function to effectively get the value out –

```
(double '(1 2 3) identity)
;; => '(2 4 6)
```

Racket allows you to easily specify default arguments, so we can modify `double` to use `identity` as the default continuation

```
(define (double xs (return identity))
  ;; ...
  )
```

This style results in convenient programs that work in two call styles at simultaneously: continuation-passing style –

```
(double '(10 11 12) print)
;; '(20 22 24)
;; => #<void>

(double '(10 11 12) length)
;; => 3

(double '(10 11 12) car)
;; => 20

(double '(10 11 12) cdr)
;; => '(22 24)
```

... *or* in direct style, using the default `identity` continuation

```
(print (double '(10 11 12)))
;; '(20 22 24)

(length (double '(10 11 12)))
;; => 3

(car (double '(10 11 12)))
;; => 20

(cdr (double '(10 11 12)))
;; => '(22 24)
```

Answer (score 0):

use map.

(map (lambda (a) (* a 2)) '(1 2 3))

Comment: It works though. I use tail recursive for practicing.

Answer (score 0):

For nested lists:

```
(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (null? x))
       (not (pair? x))))

(define (lst-double-helper lst acc)
  (cond ((empty? lst) acc)
        ((atom? (car lst)) (lst-double-helper (rest lst) (cons (* (first lst) 2) acc)))
        (else (lst-double-helper (rest lst) (cons (lst-double (first lst))
                                         acc) ))))

(define (lst-double lst)
  (reverse ; required to restore original order
   (lst-double-helper lst '())))
```

but actually to make this function tail-recursive is a little bit meaningless,
because as @simmone mentioned, `map` would do it

```
(define (list-doubler lst) 
  (map (lambda (x) (* 2 x)) lst))


(list-doubler '(1 2 3))
;; '(2 4 6)
```